# Taking in two functions and returning a function that adds their results

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that takes a polynomial data type and compiles it into the function it represents.

For instance (Constant 4) is just the constant 4,

(Add Poly Poly) could be Add (Constant 1) (Constant 4)

In which the function should return the function (\n->1+4)

If it was Add (Constant 1) Variable, the function should return (\n->1+n).

The issue is that at the top level, I've got

```
makePoly :: Poly -> (Int->Int)
makePoly (PConst n) = \n->n
makePoly (Add p1 p2) = makePoly p1 ?? makePoly p2 <- what should I do here?
```

How do I compile these 2 returned functions (feasibly coming back as (\n->n) (\n->n) if they were both constants) into an addition?  Should I add a helper function that takes in two functions and returns the sum of their outputs?

Edit: And if this is the case, how would I go about doing that?

```
add :: (Int->Int)->(Int->Int)->(Int->Int)
add f g = ?
```

Edit again: Answer for anyone searching, given by @user5402:

```
makePoly (Add p1 p2) = (\n -> (makePoly p1) n + (makePoly p2) n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
makePoly (Add p1 p2) = (\n -> (makePoly p1) n + (makePoly p2) n)
```

Explantation:

1. Create the first poly: `makePoly p1`
2. Evaluate it at `n`:  `(makePoly p1) n`
3. Same with the second: `(makePoly p2) n`
4. Add them together and wrap in a lambda.

This should also tell you how to define `add f g`.

You also have a problem here:

```
makePoly (PConst n) = \n->n
                       ^
```

The third `n` will refer to the second `n`, not the first `n`.

Comment: Thank you!  So perhaps like makePoly (PConst x) = \n->x  ?

Comment: Also, as an aside... do you know how can I get GHCI to print the representation of the function that was returned for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes to your correction of the `PConst` case. Since `n` is never used, you may also write: ` ... = \\_ -> x`

Comment: You can't print a function - i.e. functions do not have a `Show` instance.